# R - Find which value of a data frame to minimize a sum

Tags: r

In R, I have the data frame which follows :

```
Mean_1     Mean_2        Nb_element_1     Nb_element_2
42.66667   51.89474      3                38
65.00000   -85.87500     1                8
163.32653  -117.96970    49               33
22.83333   247.00000     6                1
```

I would solve this optimization problem which follows :

(1) : argmin Sum(| |Mean_1| - |Mean_2| | + |nb_element_1-nb_element_2|)

(2) : 1.1*|Mean_1| > |Mean_2| > 0.75*|Mean_1|

I want to find which elements give the smallest sum value constrained by (2)

Is there a function which can do that ? Like solve() where we have to solve (1) = 0 or others functions ?

Thank You.

Edit : What I wanted is to have the best combination between an element from Mean_1 and Mean_2 that give the smallest sum value, example :

```
(Mean_1[1],Nb_element_1[1]) with (Mean_2[3],Nb_element_2[3])
(Mean_1[2],Nb_element_1[2]) with (Mean_2[1],Nb_element_2[1])
(Mean_1[3],Nb_element_1[3]) with (Mean_2[4],Nb_element_2[4])
(Mean_1[4],Nb_element_1[4]) with (Mean_2[2],Nb_element_2[2])
```

Give the smallest sum value (not in this particular case, it's just an example to explain)

Actually, Mean_1 and Nb_element_1 are associated as Mean_2 and Nb_element_2.

So it faciliates the problem.

Thank you again.

Comment: There is no such ready-to-go function for "tables" (dataframes, matrix) in R, to my knowledge. You would have to write your own routines from existing R packages for LP, e.g. LPSolve..

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work ?

```
df <- read.table(text="Mean_1     Mean_2        Nb_element_1     Nb_element_2
42.66667   51.89474      3                38
65.00000   -85.87500     1                8
163.32653  -117.96970    49               33
22.83333   247.00000     6                1",header=TRUE,sep="")

solve1 <- function(df){
  coords <- expand.grid(1:nrow(df),1:nrow(df))
  df <- cbind(df[coords[[1]],c(1,3)],df[coords[[2]],c(2,4)])
  df <- transform(df,
                sum_value = abs(abs(Mean_1) -abs(Mean_2)) + abs(Nb_element_1-Nb_element_2),
                constraint_test = 1.1*abs(Mean_1) > abs(Mean_2) & abs(Mean_2) > 0.75*abs(Mean_1))
  # head(df)
  # Mean_1   Mean_2 Nb_element_1 Nb_element_2 sum_value constraint_test
  # 1    42.66667 51.89474            3           38  44.22807           FALSE
  # 2    65.00000 51.89474            3           38  48.10526            TRUE
  # 3   163.32653 51.89474            3           38 146.43179           FALSE
  # 4    22.83333 51.89474            3           38  64.06141           FALSE
  # 1.1  42.66667 51.89474            1           38  46.22807           FALSE
  # 2.1  65.00000 51.89474            1           38  50.10526            TRUE
  result <- df[which(df$sum_value == min(subset(df,constraint_test)$sum_value)),]
}

r <- solve1(df)
# Mean_1   Mean_2 Nb_element_1 Nb_element_2 sum_value constraint_test
# 2.16     65 51.89474            1            1  13.10526            TRUE
```

Comment: It's not what I wanted,  sum_value have to be the sum of each row not only one row, I edited my post, i didn't explain correctly my problem, sorry

Comment: but if the sum is made on all rows it'd be a constant for the problem wouldn't it ?

Comment: Not all row, but combination between an element from Mean_1 and Mean_2

(Mean_1[1],Nb_element_1[1]) with (Mean_2[3],Nb_element_2[3])
(Mean_1[2],Nb_element_1[2]) with (Mean_2[1],Nb_element_2[1])
(Mean_1[3],Nb_element_1[3]) with (Mean_2[4],Nb_element_2[4])
(Mean_1[4],Nb_element_1[4]) with (Mean_2[2],Nb_element_2[2])

Comment: alright, I expanded your data.frame to compute all possible combinations then ran the same code, now I have a solution

Comment: I think with expand.grid I can do something

Edit : Ok I'll see it, thanks, hah didn't see you use expand.grid too

Comment: sum_value has to be sum of :

(Mean_1[1],Nb_element_1[1]) with (Mean_2[3],Nb_element_2[3]) (Mean_1[2],Nb_element_1[2]) with (Mean_2[1],Nb_element_2[1]) (Mean_1[3],Nb_element_1[3]) with (Mean_2[4],Nb_element_2[4]) (Mean_1[4],Nb_element_1[4]) with (Mean_2[2],Nb_element_2[2])

not from the row considarated

Comment: Sorry... I'm trying hard but I don't get it. Do you or don't you have a sum of value for each combination of (Mean1 Nbelement1) and (Mean2 Nbelement2) ? If so we should be almost there. It would really help to have a simple example including the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dyplr)

mydf <- read.table(text = "Mean_1     Mean_2        Nb_element_1     Nb_element_2
42.66667   51.89474      3                38
65.00000   -85.87500     1                8
163.32653  -117.96970    49               33
22.83333   247.00000     6                1", header=TRUE)
```

I'll create 3 new column names "ConcolX" (for "Constraint Columns") - had to give them some name.

I think your original dataframe has no rational solution, so here I try a brute force approach with integers permuted between 0 and 200 for all 4 columns. You can refine the search space with more accurate estimates that you might have.

```
mydf3 <- expand.grid(seq(0,200,3), seq(0,200,4), seq(0,200,5), seq(0,200,4))
colnames(mydf3) <- c("Mean_1", "Mean_2", "Nb_element_1", "Nb_element_2")

mydf3 <- mydf3 %>%
        mutate(Concol1 = abs(Mean_1) - abs(Mean_2) + abs(Nb_element_1) + abs(Nb_element_2)) %>%
        mutate(Concol2 = 1.1 * abs(Mean_1) > abs(Mean_2)) %>%
        mutate(Concol3 = abs(Mean_2) > 0.75 * abs(Mean_1)) %>%
        filter(Concol2 == TRUE & Concol3 == TRUE) %>%
        filter(Concol1 == min(Concol1))
```

Result:

```
mydf3
  Mean_1 Mean_2 Nb_element_1 Nb_element_2 Concol1 Concol2 Concol3
1    171    188            0            0     -17    TRUE    TRUE
2    183    200            0            0     -17    TRUE    TRUE
```